# Merge Duplicate Rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database like this:

```
users
id    name    email                phone
1     bill    bill@fakeemail.com
2     bill    bill@fakeemail.com   123456789
3     susan   susan@fakeemail.com
4     john    john@fakeemail.com   123456789
5     john    john@fakeemail.com   987654321
```

I want to merge records considered duplicates based on the email field.

Trying to figure out how to use the following considerations.

1. Merge based on duplicate email
2. If one row has a null value use the row that has the most data.
3. If 2 rows are duplicates but other fields are different then use the one

with the highest id number (see the john@fakeemail.com row for an example.)

Here is a query I tried:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE users.id NOT IN 
(SELECT grouped.id FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (email) * FROM users) AS grouped)
```

Getting a syntax error.

I'm trying to get the database to transform to this, I can't figure out the correct query:

```
users
id   name    email                 phone
2    bill    bill@fakeemail.com    123456789
3    susan   susan@fakeemail.com   
5    john    john@fakeemail.com    987654321
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option using a delete join:

```
DELETE
FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id
                 FROM (
                     SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1
                                 THEN MAX(id)
                                 ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN phone IS NOT NULL THEN id END) END AS id
                     FROM users
                     GROUP BY email) t);
```

The logic of this delete is as follows:

- Emails where there is only one record are not deleted
- For emails with two or more records, we delete everything except for the record having the highest `id` value, where the phone is also defined.

Comment: Does this factor in if there is more than 2 duplicates? eg say there is 5 duplicates?

Comment: No, it doesn't, but then again your question makes no mention of this.

Comment: Yeah sorry, there could potentially be multiple duplicates

Comment: @Jordash I updated my answer per your new requirements.

Comment: I'm not seeing where the Email column is referenced, shouldn't it be `GROUP BY email` ?

Comment: You're right.  Keep in mind that we can't easily test a delete query locally.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that will give you the latest data for each field for each user in the result table, thus meeting your second criterion as well as the first and third. It will work for as many duplicates as you have, subject to the [`group_concat_max_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) condition on `GROUP_CONCAT`. It uses [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to prepare a list of all values of a field for each user, sorted so that the most recent value is first. [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) is then used to extract the first value in that list, which is the most recent. This solution uses a [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html) command to make a new `users` table, then `DROP`s the old one and renames the new table to `users`.

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(5), `email` varchar(19), `phone` int)
;

INSERT INTO users
    (`id`, `name`, `email`, `phone`)
VALUES
    (1, 'bill', 'bill@fakeemail.com', 123456789),
    (2, 'bill', 'bill@fakeemail.com', NULL),
    (3, 'susan', 'susan@fakeemail.com', NULL),
    (4, 'john', 'john@fakeemail.com', 123456789),
    (5, 'john', 'john@fakeemail.com', 987654321)
;

CREATE TABLE newusers AS
SELECT id
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(names, ',', 1) AS name
     , email
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(phones, ',', 1) AS phone
FROM (SELECT id
           , GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY id DESC) AS names
           , email
           , GROUP_CONCAT(phone ORDER BY id DESC) AS phones
      FROM users
      GROUP BY email) u;

DROP TABLE users;

RENAME TABLE newusers TO users;

SELECT * FROM users
```

Output:

```
id  name    email                   phone
1   bill    bill@fakeemail.com      123456789
4   john    john@fakeemail.com      987654321
3   susan   susan@fakeemail.com     (null)
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d76b12/1)

Comment: Dropping table users will fail if there is any relation to other table.

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius agreed, but so will deleting rows.